# How to access template of element

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, datatemplate

I have a `Control` with a `ScrollViewer` inside its `ControlTemplate` (inside the `Style`), I want to access that `ScrollViewer` to work together with a `ScrollSynchronizer`.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39244/Scroll-Synchronization

Here's the `Style` of the control:

```
<!--ZoomControl-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ZoomBox}">
    <Setter Property="ClipToBounds" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ZoomBox}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" ClipToBounds="True"
                              Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                              UseLayoutRounding="True"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                          Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                          UseLayoutRounding="True">
                        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                 UseLayoutRounding="True">
                            <Image Name="ImageCtrl" Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource, 
                                   Converter={StaticResource UriToBitmapConverter}}" 
                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
private static void OnScrollGroupChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = d as ScrollViewer;

    if (scrollViewer == null && d.GetType() == typeof (ZoomBox))
    {
        //FindResource always returns null.
        scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)(d as ZoomBox).FindResource("ScrollViewer");
    }
    //...
}
```

---

I also tried to create a public `Getter` inside the custom control:

```
public ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer()
{
    return Template.FindName("ScrollViewer", this) as ScrollViewer;
}
```

This same code works when inside the `OnApplyTemplate()` method. But on this case, `Resources` is null or empty.

### Edit:

The `ScrollSynchronization` class works while grouping `ScrollViewer` elements using a `AttachedProperty`:

```
<n:ZoomBox x:Name="ZoomBoxControl" util:ScrollSynchronizer.ScrollGroup="Group1"/>

<ScrollViewer x:Name="SideScrollViewer" util:ScrollSynchronizer.ScrollGroup="Group1"/>
```

So, the maybe the `Zoombox` element is not even initialized before the `OnScrollGroupChanged` fired. That may explain why the `Resource` is always empty.

### Edit 2:

One possible solution may be set the `AttachedProperty` after the window loading via code.

### Edit 3:

This code works, it runs at the `Window_OnLoaded` event, I just wish I could use xaml to attach the properties.

```
ScrollSynchronizer.SetScrollGroup(ZoomBoxControl.GetScrollViewer(), "Canvas");
ScrollSynchronizer.SetScrollGroup(MainScrollViewer, "Canvas");
```

I looked at the Visual Tree after the `OnGroupChanged` was called and it looks like the `AttachedProperty` is resolved as soon as the `ZoomBox` element is interpreted, but before its initialization. So there is no `Template` loaded yet.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are writing a custom control, so you have a class somewhere deriving from `Control` or a `FrameworkElement`-derived class:

Just tested and this works perfectly for me:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "ScrollViewer", Type = typeof(ScrollViewer))]
public class ZoomBox : Control
{
    private ScrollViewer _scrollViewerPart;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        _scrollViewerPart = GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as ScrollViewer;
    }

    public ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer()
    {
        return _scrollViewerPart;
    }
}
```

As the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) writes about `OnApplyTemplate`:

> Derived classes of FrameworkElement can use this method as a notification for a variety of possible scenarios:
>
> - You can run code that relies on the visual tree from templates having been applied, such as obtaining references to named elements that came from a template.

Comment: Yes, `ZoomBox` derives from `Control`, but on my case the `ScrollSynchronization` is an `AttachedProperty`. I'll update my question.

Comment: `_scrollViewerPart` is null and the `Template.FindName` fails, maybe the `ZoomBox` element did not initialize.

Comment: I have never seen `Template.FindName` used in this way. A cursory search suggests that `GetTemplateChild` is the correct method to use. See [relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19465736/394326).

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi your code is correct but not on my specific case. The only way I could find was using code behind.